# Creating new variables in R based on variable values of different rows in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, df,  like the following:

```
id  t  Happiness  Wealth    
1   1   5          100
2   1   5          100
3   1   5          100
1   2   3           70
2   2   9          170
3   2   2           60
```

Is there a way to subset the data so that I can create a new variable that represents the Wealth of an individual (id) in the previous time? So, the value for person 2 at time 2 will be 100.

Comment: Maybe look at the `group_by`/`lag()` functions from `dplyr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same by simply merging:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
            t = c(1, 2, 1, 2),
            wealth = c(10, 15, 12, 17))
previous <- df
previous[,"t"] <- previous[,"t"] +1
df <- merge(df, previous, by = c("id", "t"), all = TRUE, suffixes = c("_current", "_previous"))
na.omit(df)

  id t wealth_current wealth_previous
2  1 2             15              10
5  2 2             17              12
```